# How to update Survey Design with new Column/Factor

Tags: r, survey

I want to add a new column by updating my survey design but am not sure how to do so. I am using the following website which has been a big help: http://asdfree.com/survey-of-consumer-finances-scf.html

I am using the survey of consumer finance data to come up with summaries of financial assets by various groupings. This survey has respondents answering questions and the portion I'm intersted in is the financial holdings section, in particular networth.

I first download and import the data:

```
library(lodown)
lodown( "scf" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )

library(lodown)
# examine all available SCF microdata files
scf_cat <-
    get_catalog( "scf" ,
        output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" ) )

# 2007 only
scf_cat <- subset( scf_cat , year == 2007 )
# download the microdata to your local computer
scf_cat <- lodown( "scf" , scf_cat )
```

I then construct a multiply-imputed, complex sample survey design as described in the website above:

```
scf_imp_2007 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2007.rds" ) )
scf_rw_2007 <- readRDS( file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "SCF" , "scf 2007 rw.rds" ) )

scf_design_2007 <-


svrepdesign( 
         weights = ~wgt , 
         repweights = scf_rw_2007[ , -1 ] ,
  data = imputationList( scf_imp_2007 ) ,
         scale = 1 ,
         rscales = rep( 1 / 998 , 999 ) ,
         mse = FALSE ,
         type = "other" ,
        combined.weights = TRUE
     )
```

The data has various columns but I am interested in grouping "networth" by "income". While I can do the following

```
scf_MIcombine( with( scf_design_2007 ,
    svyby( ~ networth , ~ income , svytotal )
) )
```

I don't think that's right and even if it was, I get a list of each respondents income and corresponding networth, I would like to update the design and add a new column that groups all respondents networth into 1 of 4 income buckets:

0-100k,
100k-200k,
200k-400k,
Greater than 400k

So that I can then get an idea of how networth is spread across various income brackets. Any thoughts on how I could do this? I've tried searching the forum but haven't had any luck. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modifying the `hhsex` example in [variable recoding step](http://asdfree.com/survey-of-consumer-finances-scf.html#variable-recoding-50), maybe

```
income_cat = 
    factor( 
        1 + findInterval( 
                income , 
                c( 100000 , 200000 , 400000 )
            ) ,
        levels = 1:4 , 
        labels = c( 'below 100k' , '100k - below 200k' , '200k - below 400k' , '400k+' )
    )
```

then inside your `svyby()` use `income_cat` rather than `income`

Comment: this is great Anthony, thank you very much! Worked perfectly.